# Silverlight 4 app, controls disappeared?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Trying to figure out why my silverlight app suddenly just displays nothing (right click shows silverlight) when i run it and also nothing when i open the html-document created by VS2010?

This happened all of a sudden and i have no idea why. I have even deleted all my code behind except for an event.

Silverlight code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="395" d:DesignWidth="399"
             xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Image Height="96"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="55,34,0,0"
               Name="image1"
               Stretch="Fill"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Width="71" />
        <Image Height="96"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="155,34,0,0"
               Name="image2"
               Stretch="Fill"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Width="71" />
        <Image Height="96"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="257,34,0,0"
               Name="image3"
               Stretch="Fill"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Width="71" />
        <Image Height="96"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="55,270,0,0"
               Name="image4"
               Stretch="Fill"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Width="71" />
        <Image Height="96"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="155,270,0,0"
               Name="image5"
               Stretch="Fill"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Width="71" />
        <Image Height="96"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="257,270,0,0"
               Name="image6"
               Stretch="Fill"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Width="71" />
        <Button Content="Draw/Next"
                Height="23"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="155,159,0,0"
                Name="button1"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Width="71" />
        <sdk:Label Height="43"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Margin="33,173,0,0"
                   Name="label1"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Width="44"
                   Content=""
                   FontSize="32" />
        <sdk:Label FontSize="32"
                   Height="43"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                   Margin="0,173,52,0"
                   Name="label2"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Width="44"
                   Content="" />
        <Button Content="Restart"
                Height="23"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="155,217,0,0"
                Name="button2"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Width="71"
                Click="button2_Click" />       
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you check that your app.xaml.cs code behind is setting the RootVisual correctly?

Comment: This?
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            this.RootVisual = new MainPage();
        }

Comment: Yeah, not sure.  I must be missing something.  Try removing all the images you have there and just leave the buttons and remove the event wiring as well.

Comment: Now it started to work again for some strange reason. I mean, the images did nothing?

Comment: Place the content back one at a time until it breaks again.  Also, did you try running this in debug mode?  Perhaps there's a runtime exception firing and not being reported.

Comment: I did try it in debug-mode but nothing changed. Right now, after i deleted the images and recreated the, everything is working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved after deleting all contents and recreating them again. Very strange behaviour.